# Creating instance of Object not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can create the correct instance in HomeController, but cannot in MyController. Why is that?

HomeController:

```
class HomeController < AuthenticatedController
  def index
     @malls = Mall.where(:store => "Macys")
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="mall_data" data-mall-data="<%= @malls.to_json %>"></div>
```

The `#mall_data` div contains the correct json.

---

In MyController:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @malls = Mall.where(:store => "Macys")
  end
end
```

my_index.html.erb:

```
<div id="mall_data" data-mall-data="<%= @malls.to_json %>"></div>
```

The `#mall_data` contains null instead of json data.

Comment: Are you sure the controller method for MyController is getting invoked?

Comment: @BrunoRomaszkiewicz How do I invoke that?

Comment: You're gonna have to check your routes.rb file for something like `get :my_controller, to: 'my_controller#index'` or `resources :my_controller`

Comment: @BrunoRomaszkiewicz None of those seem to work. I have `root :to => 'home#index'` in routes.rb if that matters...

Comment: Are those the actual filenames of your templates? Rails will not know to look for `my_index.html.erb` by default it will look for `app/views/my/index.html.erb`.